# why my widget broadcast receiver service stops when the main app stops

Tags: android, service, widget, broadcastreceiver, android-widget

I have a widget that implements a specific broadcast receiver service to detect when the wifi connection goes down.

It works perfectly if the main activity is running or not.

The issue I have is when I stop the main activity then the broadcast receiver service stops as I don't detect anymore the wifi changes.

Is there a way to startservice that survives the main activity?

if not, any other mechanisms?

Comment: Make your broadcast receiver/service be in other process (using [`android:process`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#proc)).

Comment: I haven't thought of this approach. It makes the solution a bit more complicated. Funny enough the BR and alarm manager survive an exit from the main activity but not for example shared pref. Thanks for responding!

Comment: I don't get your question. If you define your broadcast receiver in the `manifest ` file. It will be called even if your app is closed. Then you need a simple `if statement` to check if you have connectivity or not. Why do you need a service?

Comment: It is true until Oreo. O stops the BR. I found a workaround: BR started in an alarm manager is not stopped in O. So I start an AM with a high repeatin interval.

Comment: @narb, if you make some pending intent for your receiver and schedule it by alarm manager, it doesn't matter if your activity closed or opened... and this will be true even on API Oreo.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to register your receiver in manifest and mark it as `exported=true`, so it can work if the app is not running. Check this link for detailed info please https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: I don't think this is the point. Exported is used to receive or not broadcasts from sources outside of the app.

Comment: @Nazariy Moshenskiy exported=true is by default in components if you didnt override that, lol

Comment: @HeyAlex no, it's not always false. read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element#exported but in his case you are right.

Comment: oh well, yes, my fault, but it still not a problem if exported false, because when you scheduling intent for alarm manager, you should use PendingIntent for this purpose, that means that intent will have all permissions to lunch your receiver.

Comment: @HeyAlex ok, thank you for information. i need to read more about that

Answer (score 1):

Why have I been down voted?

I've found a workaround: Broadcast Receivers started in an alarm manager are not stopped (when the main activity stops) in O. So I start an AM with a high repeatin interval.

Comment: you're being downvoted because your answer is wrong